# What's the point of logical operators vs. bitwise operators

Tags: c++, c, bitwise-operators

Given this statement is a logical operation

```
 ((a > 5) && (b > 4))
```

And this statement is bitwise-operation

```
   ((a > 5) & (b > 4))
```

Above two statements is not equivalent.

Because `(a > 5)` is an element of `{0,1}`

So, why do we need `logical operators & bitwise-operation`?

**Edit**:  thanks for all of the feedback. Regarding the short circuit behaviour of logical operators, I actually do not want this behaviour - I am writing code for a GPU where branches degrade performance:  short circuit results in two branches instead of one in the code.

For numerical comparisons in C, in the case where short circuit is not needed, it seems that logical and bitwise have identical behaviour.  In my case, bitwise ops are faster than logical.

I apologize for not putting these details in the original posting.

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.13

Answer (score 6):

I think no, take this example (0b - means binary):

```
a = 0b00000010
b = 0b00000100
```

Now, neither `a` nor `b` is 0. But `a & b == 0` (due to the way bitwise AND is defined).

However `a && b != 0` (because for logical AND result is 0 if at least one operand is 0 - this is not the case with `a` and `b` above).

---

Also there is short circuit evaluation, if in `&&` left operand is 0, the right one will not be evaluated because result is certainly 0 (e.g., as already mentioned `0 && x == 0` no matter value of `x`).

Answer (score 1):

Logical operators are to compare multiple values true-itiveness.

For example, you use the `&&` operator to see if two values are both `true`.

---

Bit-wise operators are for isolating and modifying bits in a value.

For example, in order to turn off all the bits in an 8-bit value except for one, you would do this:

```
val & 00100000
```

In the above example, the 6th (1-based) or 5th (0-based) bit is kept as it was, and the other bits are turned off.

---

Both types of operators are similar in that they both either yield 0 or 1.

For example, take these:

```
1 || 0
```

The above would yield `1` because either of the values is equal to `1`. However, if we switch the operator to `&&`, it would yield 0.

Out of all the operators you try, they will all either give `1` or `0`, `true` or `false`. That is because there is no between: there is no such thing as an expression evaluating to "sort-of true" or "maybe false".

And I think the reason why a bit-wise operator always "yields" 1 or 0 is pretty self explanatory: **bit**-wise; a bit is either 1 or 0.

Comment: It does not explain the difference of the comparisons. Note that a comparison results in integer `0` or `1`, nothing else.

Comment: @Olaf It does not explain the differences? I figured looking at the first line of each section would explain the difference. What do you recommend I discuss?

Comment: `a > 5` yields either `0` or `1`. `b > 4` likewise. Appling the bitops yields `0` or `1`, the same as the logops. So, for the question, the result will be the same (at least for C, which returns an `int` for comparisons, etc). Yet there is a significant difference in behaviour.

Comment: @Olaf I updated my answer. Tell me what you think; I may have misinterpreted your comment.

Comment: Please read my last sentence **very** carefully. If you program in C, you will likely have exploitet the difference already (I always wonder why this is forgotten so often). Note this property is not only C, but most other languages have it. Including Python. IIRC, Ada has two variants of logops (there is a slight uncertainty it was a different language).

Comment: FYI: Carefull what you state:-): For ""sort-of true" or "maybe false" you should have a look at Fuzzy Logic.

Comment: @Olaf I guess I don't have enough knowledge of C to understand what you are referencing to. I thought I covered everything, except the fact that these can both be used in conditional expressions.

Comment: Ok, next hint: what is the problem with `(p != NULL) & (p->value == 1)` (assuming corrrect types)?

Comment: @Olaf Perhaps that it has the same behavior as `&&`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88322/discussion-between-olaf-and-sirpython).

Answer (score 1):

Not all expressions used as booleans evaluate to either 0 or 1; while 0 is treated as false, anything other than 0 is treated as true.  So, for example, `1 && 2` would be true, but `1 & 2` would not, even though both 1 and 2 would be considered true.

Also, as others have pointed out, the logical operators will not evaluate the second expression if the first is enough to determine the overall value ('short-circuiting'), which obviously cannot be done with the bitwise version (well, not as often; `0 & ?` will be 0 no matter what ? is, and thus ? wouldn't need to be evaluated to get the final value, but `&` doesn't work that way).

Comment: You forgot the most important difference which makes logops quite hard to replace by bitops.

Comment: @Olaf: Thanks for the (I presume) downvote and the non-explanation as to what the "most important difference" is.  I can't even say you are wrong (though I assume you are right), because you haven't identified what you are talking about, which limits what I and others can take away from your comment.

Comment: You should be careful with what you presume. However, I stand for what I do and will happily remove the DV once corrected (which was my idea anyway. Point is that every programmer should know about this, as most imperative programming languages support it. I'll give you the following hint: What is the problem with `(p != NULL) & (p->value == 1)` (assuming corrrect types) Please focus on the `&`, of course. (you might call me nasty, but I really think this extremely important). Please drop a comment if you edited your answer, I promise to remove the DV once that has been added.

Comment: @Olaf: Could not care less about the DV, but glad to see you this this is so important a point that you feel the need to turn it into a guessing game.

Comment: Don't you agree this the most important difference? Without this, expressions like the above would be impossible and much more difficult to implement, even more for loop-conditions. For the "game": I'm very sure you will remember this from now on. Perhaps in asociation with an <insert whatever you now think of me>, but you will :-) Never mind! (as promised, I removed the DV)